# React JS Field Formik lifecycle, Field child hasn't the same props of Parent Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a parent component with Formik

Component Parent

```
<Formik
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      render={({ props }) => (
       //… more code 
       <ChildrenComponent props={props} />
      )}
   />
```

Component Children

```
import ExternalLib from "external_lib";
function ChildrenComponent ({classes, ...props}) {
    <ExternalLib
          catalogos={state.nacionalidades}
          classes={classes}
          name={"Applicant.TypeOfPerson.Nationality"}
          label={"Nacionalidades"}
          setFieldValue={props.setFieldValue}
      />
}
```

External Library

This external lib will have the functionality of an autocomplete text to find the Nationalities, Countries, etc.

```
export default class ExternalLib extends Component {
//…more code
return (
       <div ref={this.divWidth}>
                <Formik> // The lifecycle of this Formik is different than TransactForm for that reason 
                         //my  Field  called "Applicant.TypeOfPerson.Nationality" doesn’t save the 
                         //value unless if I use the registerField of this Formik and do the same with 
                         //the props.registerField from parent Formik. And the 
                         //validationSchema from Formik parent doesn’t work with this field for the 
                         //same reason (the lifecycle of this Formik is different than Formik parent).
                         //Is there a way to pass the Formik props Parent in the Formik of this 
                         //library?
            <Field
name={this.props.name} // the props.name is  //__"Applicant.TypeOfPerson.Nationality” sent by the children component
            type="text"
            label={this.props.label}
            fullWidth
            component={TextField}
            autoComplete="off"
            required
            onKeyUp={this.onKeyUp}
            InputProps={{
              onBlur:this.onBlur,
              classes: {
                  input: "Field-fontFamily",
                }
            }}
          />
        </Formik>
        {suggestionsListComponent}
      </div>
    );
}
```

The lifecycle of this Formik is different than TransactForm for that reason my  Field  called "Applicant.TypeOfPerson.Nationality" doesn’t save the           value unless if I use the registerField of this Formik and do the same with the props.registerField from parent Formik. And the validationSchema from Formik parent doesn’t work with this field for the same reason (the lifecycle of this Formik is different than Formik parent).
Is there a way to pass the Formik props Parent in the Formik of this library?

Formik version 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on the structure of your custom components or what you're trying to accomplish with 2 Formik components.  You can remove the `render` prop off of the first `Formik` and replace it with a `component` prop that defines a custom component which will be passed all of the props, but you'll need to manage them manually within.

Or you could just put a `<Field/>` component within the render prop and assign your custom component on that like `<Field name="application.typeofperson.nationality" component={MyComponent}/>`.  It may be easier to combine all the functionality you need into one component instead of passing down the props multiple levels.